# Is there a way to export Metadata from Azure Datafactory to a CSV file?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I intend to export a list of files in a ADLS folder to a CSV file using Azure DataFactory.

For instance, I have the following folder structure.

```
ADLS > FOLDER1 > File1
                 File2
                 File3
```

Now, I am using the Get Metadata activity in Azure DataFactory to get the child items.

```
{
        "childItems": [
            {
                "name": "DemoFile1",
                "type": "File"
            },
            {
                "name": "DemoFile2",
                "type": "File"
            } ],
       "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
       "executionDuration": 0
}
```

I want to export this output into a CSV file.
Is there a way?

Comment: Does it need to be automated? Does it need to be done by ADF? Personally I would write some PowerShell inside an Azure Automation runbook to do this.

Comment: It needs to be done by ADF. I want to execute it using a simple pipeline.

Comment: To do that I’m afraid your pipeline is not going to be simple.

Comment: Are you after a simple solution or an ADF solution? There are many ways to do what you want but it really depends on your true constraints. Here is one method to parse JSON as CSV in ADF, but it uses mapping data flows, which is additional complexity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse

Comment: Strictly speaking you could still use a simple pipeline.... but call an Azure function or Azure Automation script from it.

Comment: Actually this might be a simpler way to flatten your JSON https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten but it still uses mapping data flows.

Comment: I have no issue with using DataFlows. These links seem very helpful. Will try them out.

Comment: If you get a good result, please come back and post an answer explaining it

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options to store the list of source file names into CSV.

***Option1:***

As mentioned by @Nick.McDermaid in the comments section, you can use flatten transformation in data flow bypassing the get metadata output to data flow activity in the pipeline as I have repro’d in my lab.

**Input:**

[image]

1. Using `Get Metadata` activity get the list of files from a folder.

[image]

2. Create an **array variable** and a **string variable** to store the values.

[image]

3. Pass the Get Metadata output child items to the `ForEach` activity. Add append variable activity inside Foreach activity to add all the file names to an array variable

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

`@item().name`

[image]

4. Convert the array variable to a string value and store it in the string variable created earlier.

`@join(variables('file_list'),',')`

[image]

Set variable output:

[image]

5. Create a `data flow` to flatten and add it after the set variable.

[image]

**Data Flow:**

6. First create a **parameter** inside data flow to store the pipeline variable.

[image]

7. Connect the **source** to a dummy file.

[image]

8. Add `derived column` transformation to convert the string parameter value to an array.

`split($get_metadata_output, ',')`

[image]

9. Add `flatten` transformation after derived column and flatten the metadata column which is created in the derived column. Add mappings of metadata column under Input columns (this removes any columns extracted from dummy file).

[image]

10. Add **sink** transformation and connect to sink dataset. In settings, you can provide the sink file name.

[image]

**Pipeline:**

11. In pipeline, add data flow which is created above and pass the set variable value to the data flow parameter.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

***Option2:***

**Input:**

[image]

1. Connect `data flow` source to source dataset and provide source folder path from which folder you want to get the list of files. Do not provide the file name. In this way, it pulls all files data at once.

[image]

2. In **Source** options, give a new column name to store the file name ‘Column to store file name’ property.

[image]

3. In the Source data preview, you can see the new column file name with the file path along with data from all the files from the folder.

[image]

4. Add `Select` transformation to the source output to remove all the other columns from the source except the file_name.

[image]

5. Add `derived column` after select transformation to extract file name from the path. (column which stored file name contains the full path of the file)

`reverse(dropRight(reverse(File_name),instr(reverse(File_name),'/')-2))`

[image]

6. Add `aggregate` transformation to get the distinct record values from the File_name column.

[image]

[image]

7. Add **Sink** transformation at the end and connect to sink data set. In setting, you can provide the file name to store the sink data.

[image]

Sink preview:

[image]

8. **Output:**

[image]

Comment: In the Option 1, is it really necessary to join and the to split the file names?